# php sql syntax, fetching random row w/ includes row with id variable

Tags: php, mysql, random, syntax

Apologies for not wording the title properly. I'm looking to pull a random mysql id that has genre value set to Electro

```
SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions ORDER BY rand() WHERE `$genretypefix` DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Fred solved first part, ORDER BY after WHERE.. still cannot get the variable to work though

EDIT:

```
$sorttype = $_GET['sort'];
$genretype = $_GET['gn'];
$genretypefix = "genre='" . $genretype . "'";
if ($sorttype == 'new') {
    $sql = "
SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1
";
} elseif ($sorttype == 'genre') {
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions WHERE `$genretypefix` ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 0, 1
";
} else {
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions ORDER BY played DESC LIMIT 0, 1
"; }
```

EDIT2: removed ` as per comment and it works, thank-you

Comment: Sidenote: `ORDER BY` comes after `WHERE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: You're welcome Darren.

Comment: what do you mean `can't seem to get it`? wheres the codes which does the fetching? its just a plain incorrect query in the question

Comment: So, problem solved? @DarrenMichulse

Comment: Apologies Ghost, Fred corrected my error and when I run a query in phpmyadmin (SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions WHERE genre='Electro' ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 0, 1) it works perfectly.. I've confirmed $genretypefix = "genre='Electro'" but yet it isn't returning a result. I must have gone wrong in how I used the variable in the mysql, still can't figure that part out.

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: Your WHERE clause is/seems incorrect. It should read something like `WHERE $genretypefix = 'something'` - @Ghost want a crack at this one? I'm headed off to lahlah land. My head's gone to mush.

Comment: Wait a minute, you're not querying. If you're using `mysql_` then do `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM...` - If you're using `mysqli_` then do `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM...` @DarrenMichulse while closing the bracket `)` for it `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1
");` @DarrenMichulse while closing the bracket `)`

Comment: Will learn about sqli now, thank-you! turns out I didn't need the `, which is incredibly odd and I still can't figure out why it's needed sometimes and not others.. thanks for your time fred & ghost

Comment: @DarrenMichulse credit goes to Fred :D next assignment, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @DarrenMichulse I was writing up an answer actually.

Comment: reading a quick tutorial on sqli then will swap it over, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM rtsubmissions WHERE $genretypefix ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 0, 1"
```

Comment: I suggest you wait for more code before putting in an answer, to something that has already been established. That's why comments were invented ;)

Comment: This worked! I have no idea why deleting the ` made the difference, looking through my other code it seems to require it.. thanks ashique

Comment: @DarrenMichulse You can use the ` for table and column names, which is known as an "identifier". For values (strings), double or single quotes are used.